# Especificar Path en .jar

Tags: java

Con la siguiente linea de código puedo obtener el Path de mi proyecto en java:

```
new File("").getAbsolutePath()
```

Cuando lo compilo en Eclipse no hay ningún problema, pero cuando genero el .jar me manda a otra dirección diferente.

Siempre que ejecuto el .jar me manda esta dirección
C:\WINDOWS\System32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solucion

```
new File(InstalarApps.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getAbsolutePath()
```